# Crystal Reports 11 - New page after each parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am running Crystal Reports 11 and I have a report that has 7 subreports that it pulls and when done, is multiple pages long.  I have three parameters I ask for.  I want to change one of the parameters to allow multiple fields so I don't have to keep refreshing it but I want the report to repeat for each field value I add.

Example, the report asks for month.  I want to put in January, February and March into the field value.  The report then should run for each of those months and give me one large report where January and all January data is back to back and then goes to February, etc.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Jayson

Answer (score 0):

Group the report at level one by Month.
In the Group Options tab (or in the GF1 section), turn on the 'New Page After' option.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I didn't even think about that but I have another question that has popped up.  The actual report has no table to it.  The table calls are all in the sub reports.  The main report is basically a display function.  I ask for some parameter fields and those get passed to the sub reports.  WIth that being said, I can't seem to group by Parameter fields or at least see how to do that.

Comment: Create a table with one row for each date grouping (e.g. each Month).
Use it as the data source for the main report and Group on Month.
Filter the main report based on the Month parameter. And also maintain the logic of passing that parameter to the subreports.
Move all the subreports to GH1 or GF1 (instead of RH1/RF1).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I have created a dummy table with the months in it and set the main report to read from that.  I have set the main formula to grab that data table and make it equal to the field that is being passed to the sub reports and then I setup grouping on that dummy field from the dummy table.  The report runs but it never goes to the next month if I have more than 1 month selected.  Is there a trigger that I need to enable for advancing to the next group value?

Comment: It's not clear what "field" you are referring to. 
Make sure the main report parameter for Month is set to allow multiple values.
If you unhide the detail section, it should show one record for each Month row in the dummy table. Does it?  If not, fix it so it does.

Comment: Sorry if my response wasn't complete.  The report has a parameter field of month.  Because my database stores month as a number and I want to show month to the user as the full name, I have a formula that converts the proper name to a number.  That formula field is what I pass to each subreport so if they choose January, I send 1 to the subreport.  The dummy table I create has just 1-12 in it with each number in its own row.  I have a filter to make match what the user chooses with that value in the dummy table and I am grouping on the tables dummy value.

Comment: You need to get to a point where your main report shows all matching rows from the dummy table based on the Month parameter. So set aside the subreport aspect and focus on this simple objective.  Once you get that done, follow the suggestion above about placing all the subreports in GH1 or GF1.